# Rails: Nested attributes não está inserindo valores com fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando criar um registro de carro (cars) mas de outro modelo ao mesmo tempo em que crio um morador (resident). Mas ao inserir os valores estão saindo nulos. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Resident controller

```
def new
  @resident = Resident.new
  @resident.cars.build
end

def create
  @resident = Resident.new
  @resident.cars.build
end
```

Resident model

```
class Resident < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :building
  has_many :cars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars
end
```

/residents/new.html.erb

```
...
<%= fields_for :cars do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :model %>
  <%= f.text_field :brand %>
  <%= f.text_field :color %>
  <%= f.text_field :plate %>
<% end %>
```

Abaixo segue o log.

```
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "resident"=>{"building_id"=>"1", "apartment"=>"123", "name"=>"Joaquim 2", "email"=>"uol@gmail.com", "rg"=>"123123", "cpf"=>"123123", "workphone"=>"121288", "homephone"=>"93278340", "mobile"=>"1283918", "tipo"=>"Locatario", "birthdate(1i)"=>"2022", "birthdate(2i)"=>"9", "birthdate(3i)"=>"19"}, "cars"=>{"model"=>"fusca", "brand"=>"volks", "color"=>"preto", "plate"=>"KIO12312"}, "commit"=>"Cadastrar"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `current_user'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/residents_controller.rb:40:in `create'
  Building Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `buildings`.* FROM `buildings` WHERE `buildings`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/residents_controller.rb:40:in `create'
  Resident Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `residents` (`name`, `rg`, `cpf`, `workphone`, `homephone`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `building_id`, `local`, `birthdate`, `mobile`, `tipo`, `apartment`, `email`) VALUES ('Joaquim 2', '123123', '123123', '121288', '93278340', '2022-09-19 15:15:22.289720', '2022-09-19 15:15:22.289720', 1, NULL, '2022-09-19', '1283918', 'Locatario', '123', 'uol@gmail.com')
  ↳ app/controllers/residents_controller.rb:40:in `create'
  Car Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO `cars` (`model`, `color`, `plate`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `resident_id`, `brand`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, '2022-09-19 15:15:22.293364', '2022-09-19 15:15:22.293364', 11, NULL)
  ↳ app/controllers/residents_controller.rb:40:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.5ms)  COMMIT
```

Outra pergunta =]
Como faria para criar mais carros? Apenas Repito o formulario?

Answer (score 0):

fields_for has no reference to the parent model.

Example:

```
form_with model: @resident | form |


form.fields_for :cars do | f |

…

end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

A associação com **fields_for** tem como referência o formulário pai na hora da criação. Assim como mencionado no comentário do Cleber.

```
form_with model: @resident | form |
  form.fields_for :cars do | f |
    ...
  end
end
```

Porém deve verificar os parâmetros permitidos ao adicionar os parâmetros no método **create**, junto ao build (que já está fazendo) no método **new**

Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
def new
  @resident = Resident.new
  @resident.cars.build
end

def create
  @resident = Resident.new(resident_params)
  @resident.save
end

private

def resident_params
  params.require(:resident).permit(...fields, { cars_attributes: %i[cars_fields] }
end
```

Infelizmente não consegui testar no momento, me avisa caso haja algum problema